# How do you redirect the output of lynx to print only the last 20 lines of its output?

Tags: command-line

I need help figuring out a command that will make lynx print out only the last 20 lines of the output I have for it.

I just learned `lynx -dump` and I was attempting to use it with a pipeline with the command tail:

```
lynx -dump names1990s.html | tail -20 name1990s.html
```

I'm not sure if I am using a pipeline correctly. We just learned how to pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in terminal,

```
lynx -dump /path/to/file_name.html | tail -n 20
```

It will give you last 20 lines of the output of lynx. If your html file name is `names1990s.html` and it is in your current directory, use

```
lynx -dump names1990s.html | tail -n 20
```

Comment: Perfect! I just have one question though. I was shown to use tail as: tail -1 random.txt to show the last line of something. What does the -n mean in this command?

Comment: `-n 20` is just a switch of `tail` which tells it to print last 20 lines. See [`man tail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tail.1.html) for more.